# When a set function on a product sigma-algebra is a measure

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure, product-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces.
Every measure $\mu$ on $(X\times Y, \mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B})$ gives an assignment $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}\to\Bbb{R}$ via $(A,B)\mapsto\mu(A\times B)$.

Conversely, consider an assignment $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}\to\Bbb{R}$. Under which conditions does this extend to a measure on $(X\times Y, \mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B})$?

Comment: If mu is a product of two measures, then mu extends to a measure if it is a product of two measures (I believe this extension is unique if the two measures are sigma finite).